# Touchpad not reversed anymore and device, Glib and kernel errors in log after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: touchpad, acpi, glib, 22.04

Yesterday I upgraded to 22.04 on my Dell XPS 15. After the upgrade the touchpad does not use natural scrolling anymore even if it is switched on. I see the below errors in the log after boot. Seems like there is a problem detecting the touchpad, maybe some generic driver is used instead, causing the issue? If anyone has input on the other errors it would be appreciated. Posting as one question in case they might be related.

```
21:08:38 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
21:08:37 gnome-session-b: GLib-CRITICAL: g_hash_table_foreach_remove_or_steal: assertion 'version == hash_table->version' failed
21:08:29 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
21:08:25 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
21:08:16 systemd-udevd: vboxnetctl: /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/60-virtualbox-dkms.rules:3 Only network interfaces can be renamed, ignoring NAME="vboxnetctl".
21:08:14 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
21:08:10 systemd: Failed to start LSB: Automatically mounts the lernstick exchange partition.
21:08:09 kernel: 
21:08:08 kernel: psmouse serio1: synaptics: Unable to query device: -5
21:08:08 kernel: ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
```